# Give read only access to an azure table

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I need to give read-only access to a third party to one of our Azure tables. 
Is there a clean, simple way of doing that or should I clone the table? If so, how do I clone the table?

Edit:

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn246929.aspx) the documentation on how to do it in Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no built-in mechanism for cloning a table; you'd need to do the copy yourself.

However: Your assertion about Azure Tables not supporting read-only credentials is incorrect. If all you want to do is grant read-only access, you can just create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the table in question, granting just *query* permissions, on the specific table. You can even limit it to a particular range, as defined by partition key + row key.

More info about that is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples#table-examples).

Comment: @GTPV - "as always?" Not sure what you're implying but... I posted this answer in 2015, nearly 5 years ago, including a link from 2012. I have no control over external sites and how data is moved or (in this case) archived. That said: I'm glad you brought this to my attention, so that I could update the link in question (now updated). Also, note: the original question, prior to being edited, incorrectly claimed there was no way to provide read-only access to a table, which is the basis of my answer. Storage-level SAS is well-documented now (blobs/tables/files/queues, as well as ADLS storage).

Comment: @GTPV - also, while the original reference link may have aged out, my answer still stands as correct. I noticed that this answer was downvoted the same day you posted your comment. Not sure why the downvote. Informing me of the dead link seems adequate enough.